# Moving big database from one server to another

Tags: database, migration, sql-server

I have created a website that I know that its database size will increase rapidly. It will become terabytes and by the way I don't want to get a expensive server at first. What is I'm concerned about:

1. If my cheep server is not enough, how do I move gigabytes of database to another server (considering that meanwhile the website will be in maintenance mode)
2. Is there any ways (any services) that I can have unlimited database size without worrying about database size and moving it?

PS: I'm using SQL server 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about dedicated servers, then it won't be such a big problem to transfer the database.

You can use SSH in order to transfer it directly from one server to another, without even downloading it. Then you can import it in a new database from the command line pretty fast.

If you don't want to worry about storage and performances, then go for cloud hosting. There you can upgrade/downgrade your server on the run and even set up dedicated servers for your database only ( which is a really good idea ).

Comment: As I'm really new to cloud servers, how can I set up dedicated servers for database?

Comment: You can try it with Amazon. There are a lot of tutorials related to this, but I gotta tell you it's not easy and you should hire a professional if you're not very good with servers.